# call php service codeigniter on button click using post data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, angularjs, codeigniter

```
$scope.nextbutton=function()  //on button click this function is called
{
 alert( $scope.datatopass);
 var mm=$scope.datatopass;   //contains data got from ajax response


 //here i need to call service 'preview' that loads a view with my data passed  


}
```

www.xyz.com/project/controller/preview:

```
function preview()
{

                $data= json_decode(trim(file_get_contents('php://input')),true);

        $this->load->view('preview_view',$data);
}
```

I wanted to pass data on button click from my page to controller and from there i need to redirect to page-preview_view with my $data

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is that in your angularJS function you could do it with $http. However, a better pattern would be to use a service and work through that, keeping the actual interaction with the server out of (what I presume) is your controller.

Nevertheless, try this:

```
//For angular
app.controller('someController', function($http, $scope){

  $scope.nextButton = function(){
     $http.post('/url/to/post/to', $scope.data).success(function(result){

          //Result from server
          console.log(result);
      });
    };

});
```